# Add Service Principal as Enterprise Application Owner

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I did the following to an user and an application service principal.

- Assign as Directory Reader
- Assign as an owner in an enterprise application.
- Give nothing in API permissions for the application.

The user can see and manage the enterprise application but the application service principal can only see (via MS Graph API).

How can the user manage the enterprise application, but the application service principal cannot ?

My goal is to allow the application to manage certain application only, not all. Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Update, using application service principal, I can add owner to the target enterprise application, but I cannot add user assignment.

Comment: Now that you have add the  application service principal as owner of the target enterprise application, why do you still need to add user assignment? Correct me if there is any understanding.

Comment: And the application service principal can see the target enterprise application (via MS Graph API), it should be able to manage the target enterprise application (via MS Graph API). What is your goal? Using the application service principal to manage the target enterprise application on Azure portal?

Comment: I want the service principal A to be able to manage users that is allowed to login to the target service principal ( enterprise application ) and associate the correct app role.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **Directory Reader** role won't allow you to assign app role.

What you should consider here is **Application administrator** role.

I know you want the service principal to manage only this one enterprise application. So you need to specify "scope" when assigning the AAD role.

[image]

In the screenshot above, select "Service principal" for Scope type. "testg0036" is the enterprise application and "testG006" is the application service principal.

Then testG006 can modify testg0036 but not other enterprise applications.

Comment: Hi @allen-wu 
Thanks

However, I also assign the service principal as owner of the targeted service principal, as I did with the user. 
The user can do what I want with the exactly same permission as the service principal, but the service principal can not.